# How to get Fiscal Year to only show the last 3 years

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is probably a duplicate but I couldn't find it after 10 mins of research. Here is the question:

I am trying to get the last 3 Fiscal years to show up in my query: so for me it would be 2018, 2019, and 2020.

```
        SELECT distinct E.FISCALYEAR
        FROM EMPLOYEES as E 
            INNER JOIN HR_PERIODS as H ON E.PERIOD = H.PERIOD 
        WHERE 
        E.FISCALYEAR <= year(getdate())  + 1
        and E.RECORDSTATUS = 1

        ORDER BY E.FISCALYEAR
```

The query I currently have does:

```
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
```

Also our HR Fiscal Year populates from 2015 to Present fiscal year.

Comment: When does your Fiscal year start? April? If it's not inline with the calendar year, then using the `YEAR` may not give you the answer you're after. For example, if March 2020 is part of the 2019 Fiscal year, `YEAR('20200320')` would return `2020`, which is not correct.

Comment: @Larnu it is July

Comment: You probably want a Calendar table (with your fiscal years included as columns) and you can do a simple join. Then you can use the calendar table elsewhere as well and you don't have to recreate this logic in every query.

Comment: Then even more reason to not use `YEAR` on it's own, as 6 months of the year `YEAR` would return the wrong fiscal year value. You could, however, use `YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -6, YourDate))` but, as @JacobH said, a Calendar Table would likely be a better option (as you can include other extra columns)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `top (3)`:

```
SELECT distinct TOP (3) E.FISCALYEAR
FROM RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF E INNER JOIN
     HR_PERIODS H
     ON E.PERIODNUMBER = H.PERIODNUMBER 
WHERE E.FISCALYEAR <= year(getdate())  + 1 AND
      E.EOM_RECORDSTATUS_EFF = 1
ORDER BY E.FISCALYEAR DESC
```